# How can I retrieve a model through a polymorphic intermediate - i.e. morphToOneThrough()

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8

I have 3 models: Users, PublicKeys and Metadata.  I want to be able to retrieve Metadata directly from User, but can not use `hasOneThrough()` because the interim relationship is polymorphic:

---

Users have a polymorphic one-to-one relationship with Public Keys:

```
// App\Models\User

public function publicKey(){
    return $this->morphOne('App\Models\PublicKey','keyable');
}
```

PublicKeys has a normal one-to-one relationship with Metadata

```
// App\Models\PublicKey

public function metadata(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\PublicKey');
}
```

I am looking to achieve the polymorphic equivalent of `hasOneThrough()` so that I could just call `$user->metadata` rather than `$user->publicKey->metadata`, but I can't find any combination of arguments for `hasOneThrough()` to achieve this.

The closest I have come is

```
$this->hasOneThrough('App\Models\Metadata','App\Models\PublicKey', 'keyable_id')
```

But this doesn't work as keyable_id isn't guaranteed to be unique owing to the polymorphism.

How can I achieve a `morphOneThrough()` equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

Having been working on this all day, I have a working solution based on extending the `HasOneThrough` class and adding a trait that includes elements of `MorphOne()`.  It works on simple testing as a 'HasOneThrough' including options to chain hasOne methods like `withDefault()`

**This works for the standard Laravel determined keys.  I have not tested it with custom ID and Type keys - though feel free to give it a go:**

---

**App\Models\User**

```
use MorphOneThrough;

public function metadata(){
   return $this->morphOneThrough('App\Models\Metadata','App\Models\PublicKey','keyable');
}
```

---

**App\Traits\MorphOneThrough**

```
trait MorphOneThrough
{

public function morphOneThrough($related, $through, $name, $firstKey = null, $type = null, $secondKey = null, $localKey = null, $secondLocalKey = null)
    {
        $through = new $through;

        [$type, $id] = $this->getMorphs($name, $type, $firstKey);
        $firstKey = $firstKey ?: $id;

        $secondKey = $secondKey ?: $through->getForeignKey();

        return $this->newMorphOneThrough(
            $this->newRelatedInstance($related)->newQuery(), $this, $through, $type,
            $firstKey, $secondKey, $localKey ?: $this->getKeyName(),
            $secondLocalKey ?: $through->getKeyName()
        );
    }

protected function newMorphOneThrough(Builder $query, Model $farParent, Model $throughParent, $firstTypeKey, $firstKey, $secondKey, $localKey, $secondLocalKey)
{
    return new \App\MorphOneThrough($query, $farParent, $throughParent, $firstTypeKey, $firstKey, $secondKey, $localKey, $secondLocalKey);
}
}
```

Where morphOneThrough has been adapted from HasOneThrough and MorphTo in order to work out the correct keynames from the name of the morph for `firstKey`.  `SecondKey` is left alone as the distant relationship is a normal hasOne.

---

**App\MorphOneThrough**

```
class MorphOneThrough extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneThrough

{
    protected string $morphId;
    protected string $morphType;


public function __construct(Builder $query, Model $farParent, Model $throughParent, $firstTypeKey, $firstKey, $secondKey, $localKey, $secondLocalKey)
    {
        $this->morphId = $firstKey;
        $this->morphType = $firstTypeKey;
        parent::__construct($query, $farParent, $throughParent, $this->morphId, $secondKey, $localKey, $secondLocalKey);
    }

public function addConstraints()
    {
        $localValue = $this->farParent[$this->localKey];

        $this->performJoin();

        if (static::$constraints) {
            $this->query->where([
                [$this->getQualifiedFirstKeyName(), '=', $localValue],
                [$this->throughParent->qualifyColumn($this->morphType), '=', get_class($this->farParent)]
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

In the class itself have overridden the constructor to maintain the morph column names and to pass the correct ID fields to the HasOneThrough constructor.  I then add an extra where to the QueryBuilder in addConstraints to limit to types of the correct class.